# Software to input all monthly expenses from my bank (csv) and automatic categorizing expenses

Tags: windows, linux, finance

I don't know how I'm spending my money and my bank doesn't help because it doesn't categorize the expenses. I'd like to have my expenses somehow grouped in some software that can classify automatically the expenses based on some rules set by me (example: if expense name is X then categorize it as Y).

I usually export all the expenses at the end of the month in CSV format so I'm okay with normalizing the data a bit before inserting it into the software.

What's important for me is:

- To have all the expenses as a list
- To automatically categorize expenses when they are added based on some rules
- To have some pie charts or something that you see at a glance where did the money go
- To be able to automatically import from csv or other formats
- Preferrably free (but I can check paid ones if they are really worth it)
- Linux or Windows

Nice to have:

- Automatic import from bank (although I assume that since I'm not in the US there won't be any apps that do this so...)
- Windows would be nice but if it's Linux only I can adapt if it's worth

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure if [Hibiscus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibiscus_(Software)) would fit your needs (product is from Germany, but the Wikipedia page is also available in Portuguese). It's a full-fledged banking software, open-source and all – and a.o. can also import from CSV. I've only heard good things about it.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.firefly-iii.org/ to see if it meets your needs

Comment: Hey actually firefly-iii looks very promising, my bank appeared on the supported banks list from the Spectre API, I'll take a look when I get home!

Comment: Great. I have entered a full-answer below, so that you can report any additional findings.

Comment: Thanks in the next days I will give it a try to Firefly III, I just found out that using the external API's it seems that my bank is compatible so I can automatically import expenses! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you opted for Google Sheets, you should also look at [FireFly III](https://www.firefly-iii.org/)

- "Firefly III features a double-entry bookkeeping system. You can quickly enter and organize your transactions in multiple currencies."
- It has a "special Data Importer" that supports various sources.
- It also has a Rule Engine to "to quickly convert shorthands to detailed transactions or clean up your bank's abysmal CSV"

You can try a [demo here](https://demo.firefly-iii.org/login).

Comment: I'm having some difficulties deploying Firefly III to my raspberry pi (there's nowhere else where I can deploy it) but as soon as I test it and verify it suits my needs I'll check this as the answer. Good to see there is such a cool open source project!

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets can also be used as an option. I made some custom formulas to assign categories based on some regular expressions.

This is the simplest if you don't need anything else, and if someday you want to move away from Google you can always do the exact same procedure on opensource excel-like software.

Importing the csv is pretty straightforward in a new tab and then you can copy that on the tab that has the formulas so they can get automatic tags. At the end of the formulas tab there are some percentage calculations to see where the expenses went that month.

In case anyone is interested the custom formula looks something like this (semicolons are used because in my locale commas are for numbers)

```
=IFNA(FILTER(<categories_names_range>;REGEXMATCH(<the cell with the concept of the expense>;<categories regexes range>);NOT(ISBLANK(<categories_names_range>)));"NoCategory")
```

Answer (score 0):

If web based is okay, then [**Mint**](https://mint.intuit.com/) from Intuit does it very well, I think it ticks all your boxes, and you don't even need to import anything, it picks them all up automagically from the online financial logins.

If you do want a PC application, and in general something even more robust, [**Quicken**](https://www.quicken.com/) might be a very good option. But it is not free.

Comment: Unfortunately Mint only operates on US and Canada :( Looked promising tho

Comment: What about Quicken? And also, where are you located? Maybe there is a Mint equivalent there

Comment: Spain, quicken is a bit expensive for my taste, but I'll take a closer look and decide.

Comment: Maybe something like https://www.linxo.com/ (seems to be a European competitor to Mint)

Comment: Tried linxo.com but my bank also does not appear there... I'm going to test FireFly III as other user has pointed out, because my bank appears in the list of one of the third party providers that it supports :D